# Sending an email via php mailer I get "myemail via host.blabla" in sender, how to remove that?

Tags: php, email, outlook, gmail, phpmailer

I have this phpmailer which is blasting emails and when recieving the email the sender is : myemail@myemail.com via web258.opentransfer.com (my host)

thats my code:

```
        // Real Email Blast:
        $mail = new PHPMailer();
        $mail->From = "myemail@email.com";
        $mail->FromName = "myname";
        $mail->AddAddress($email, $name);

        $mail->Subject = $htmlTitle = stripslashes($reSubject);

        $mail->Body  = $htmlBody = "
                          <div style='direction: rtl; text-align: right;'>
                          ".stripslashes($reEmailContents)."
                          </div>";
        // Setting plain text:
        $text_body  = $htmlTitle."
        ".strip_tags($htmlBody);

        $mail->AltBody = $text_body;

        if (!$mail->Send()) {
            // Email failed error, resending user to landing page:
            $error .= "<span style='color: #D20005;'>- Failed sending email to:             ".$email." (".$name.")</span><br>";
        }
```

that's especially visible on outlook and on gmail when you access the email itself you can see it on the sender box - how can I remove this and send without the host?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That's the intention of the "via yourdomainhere.com"

I don't believe you can change it, unless you run a custom mail server on your site (which may not be possible on a shared host)

Irregardless, your question would probably be better suited for ServerFault since PHPMailer isn't the issue.

Comment: I also have a dedicated server, what can be done to send the email as legit without the host?

Comment: Cant I fix it with reverse DNS?

Comment: It looks like you can. Like i said: serverfault is the place to go: http://serverfault.com/questions/30188/how-do-i-configure-reverse-dns-for-a-smtp-server